# Release IP address in Apache

Tags: node.js, apache, sockets, express, nginx

I want to run NGINX and Apache Side by Side to use Node.JS with NGINX. The problem is that NGINX is not starting. I have two IPs and at the httpd.conf of Apache I edited the "Listens" to only this:

```
Listen 1.1.1.1:80
```

And the default.conf of NGINX to:

```
server {
  listen 2.2.2.2:80 default_server;
  ...
}
```

But I'm getting this error when I start NGINX:

```
Starting nginx: nginx: [warn] server name "/var/log/nginx/access.log" has suspic ious symbols in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:41
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 2.2.2.2:80 failed (99: Cannot assign requested ad dress)
```

What am I doing wrong? I searched over the internet and I found how to configure both web servers side by side here: http://kbeezie.com/apache-with-nginx/ and I found this:

> To do this you have to make sure Apache and Nginx are bound to their
>   own IP adddress, In the event of WHM/Cpanel based webserver, you can
>   Release an IP to be used for Nginx in WHM.

But I don't have cPanel. How can I do this manually?

OBS: 1.1.1.1 and 2.2.2.2 is just an example.

Comment: Have you modified `VirtualHost`s?

Comment: No, and I don't use <VirtualHost {IPs ...}>.